# Laravel extend layout without Blade

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5

I want to extend default layout and add section for layout But I don't want to use Blade Syntax. As in phpstorm Blade syntax generates errors and IDE stop auto completion and also stop recognizing php tags at all(only after I use @ symbol in action()).

So my question is how can I convert

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
@stop
```

into php tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Laravel's source code (`Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler`) it's:

`@extends('layouts.default')`

This is the trickiest part. Normally, when you use `@extends` Laravel compiles it to this: but adds it to a `footer` variable that's echoed at the end. If you add it at the end of your view instead of the beginning it should work too. (At least it worked in a simple test I did)

```
<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.default', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

---

`@section('content')`

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
```

---

`@stop`

```
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
```

---

However if you're on PhpStorm 8, the Blade syntax is actually supported and I never had a problem with it. [*What's new in PhpStorm 8?*](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/)

Comment: I am using laravel 5 and action('ProductController@index'). I get error at @ sysmbol and phpstorm does't even recognize php tags after this execution.

Comment: Well support for the `{!! !!}` tags isn't there yet but `{{ action('ProductController@index') }}` should work fine

Comment: Also above code does't work.                                                                      syntax error, unexpected '$__env' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: The backslashes probably have been the problem. Try it again without them

Comment: Still does't work but I actually completely missed {{}}. After reading {!!!!} I gave up on laravel blade but I will stick with it. But still this answer is not correct so if you could find correct answer I will accept it. This time I don't get any error but no content shows up so I think problems lies with content section.

Comment: You have to put the "extends" part at the bottom of your view. See the edited answer...